Strimzi Kafka Connect Cluster - Resource planning
I'm planing resources which will be dedicated to run Kafka Connect Clusters in Strimzi Distribution.
My workloads are pretty small, there will be probably only 1 task per connector needed.
I would go with AKS with 2 nodes in my dedicated nodepool.
In that case should i always deploy Strimzi Kafka Connect cluster with 2 workers (pods) inside my AKS Cluster, just to achieve HA? Or just one Worker will be okay and if the node will fail, this worker (pod) will be recreated on second node with the task? Can you share some good practices of resource planning for Strimzi Kafka Connect Clusters? - When i should go with two workers etc.

Hi, did you try reading this  link  ?

@Lasha That question is about brokers, not Kafka Connect

@OneCricketeer the "correct" answer is about Brokers, not Kafka connect, may be you have missed it out, but check this: link

@Lasha Exactly. This question is about Kafka Connect rather than the brokers or Zookeeper, so that link isn't applicable here

@OneCricketeer My apologies, it's my mistake. I misunderstood the problem and thought it was about the Kafka broker. In your case, if the load is pretty small, then having one pod should be sufficient. If a node fails, Kubernetes will reschedule the Kafka Connect pod onto another node, and it will pick up the tasks. But if you already have 2 nodes why not have 2 connect pods (with pod anti-affinity, without it it will not be HA)? Also it does not consume many resources. but if you can afford it, in case of node failure, wait until Kubernetes reschedule the pod into another, its also ok i think

One worker would be fine. If that pod terminates, AKS would reschedule it. If a task fails, however, that traditionally is a manual restart process (not sure if Strimzi has a solution to this), and so multiple workers would not address this.
If you start running many connector tasks, you may want to scale out to multiple workers, but unless you setup affinity rules on the pods, the worker pods may be on only one node, so not truly addressing HA

Yes, Strimzi operator provides an option to auto restart connectors, i plan to set affinity rules for nodepool, it may address HA, thanks
